# Random background color on vuejs loop

Tags: javascript, laravel, vue.js

A little help here, I'm stuck. I don't know even how to start.
I have this v-for for printing my "contracts".
I'm still not to submerged on vuejs workflow so I'm not being able to work around this.

How can I give a diferent background-color to every col div there? But not randomly, I want for them to keep the color even if the page is reloaded, my aproach was using the id of my contract and doing something with that but I don't understand much about vuejs to know how to do it.

Let's say I want to make a javascript function to give a class depending on the contractType.id, how do I execute that function with each loop? Is there a proper way to do this on vuejs?

```
<template>
  <div class="row" v-if="contractTypes && contractTypes.length > 0">
    <div class="col-md-4 c-button" v-for="(contractType, index) in contractTypes" :key="index" @click="choose($event.srcElement.innerHTML, index, contractType.id)">
      <div class="col p-4 d-flex flex-column position-static text-center">
          <strong class="d-inline-block mb-2 text-primary">World</strong>
          <h3 class="mb-0">{{ translations && translations[contractType.id] ? translations[contractType.id].usecasetitle : contractType.usecasetitle }}</h3>
          <p class="card-text mb-auto">{{ translations && translations[contractType.id] ? translations[contractType.id].description : contractType.title }}</p>
          <button class="btn btn-primary">Click</button>
        </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div v-else>
    <h1>Leider stehen für Sie derzeit keine Verträge zur Auswahl.</h1>
  </div>
</template>
```

Comment: May be I must do a child component for the loop?

Comment: There are several ways to do this. Do specific IDs get a specific color? Or is it only based on item position (e.g., first item is red, second blue, etc.)?

Comment: No, can be any color. I was thinking to use the id just to keep the same color to the same id but any color.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If you want custom styles on the different contract types, you can d a `method`:

```
/*
 * @param {string} contract -- a foo bar
 * @return {object} -- Bunch of boolean controlled classes
 */
getContractClasses (contract)
{
  return {
    'style1': contract === 'a string',
    'style2': contract === 'another thing',
    'style3': true, // This one is always going to be on and will have a bunch of shared styles between all of them
  }
},
```

Then, in the template,

```
<h3 :class="getContractClasses(contract)">
```

Finally, just do the different styles in the style guide in the component housing the `v-for`.

Also, might I suggest an unwritten rule of sorts to remove all the logic from the template layer, and have that as a method or computed? Reading that long ternary inline is a big "No thank you", from me.

Comment: Oh, ok, I get it, every time a div gets printed calls the getClasses function that returns a value and because it's on :class the value get's added to the class of the element.
And 'style1': "contract === 'a string' " are conditionals (cool, so contracted haha).
So I can give a different style depending on the ,lets say, contractType.id.
Thanks, this works and is simple enught for me, I will play with it.
And thanks for the recomendation too, actually is not my code I don't understand it completly yet.

Comment: @arderoma  sounds like you get the idea. Thank you for following up with feedback and accepting the answer.

Comment: @arderoma Just to make sure there is no confusion, `style1` is not actually a style, but the class name to apply the style on. So in the styleguide, there will be `.style1 { background: red;}`.

Comment: Yes, I got it. <3